# Is there an alternative to inserting line breaks to move a paragraph down in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I have an image to the right of a heading and paragraph. The paragraph is shorter than the image. I want to move the **Field-level Help** heading down so that the table can expand to the right. I can certainly add some line breaks to move this. Are line breaks the best way to position the paragraph in this situation?

[image]

Comment: I think it depends on your definition of "best".  It's certainly the easiest and fastest way, and it's how I've done this in various word processors for many years.

Comment: I'd move the picture up instead. It looks unbalanced already. It will look worse with a big gap.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good idea! It does look kind of bad with that gap.

Comment: As an alternative to line breaks you can also add Points Before or Points After on any specific paragraph to get a final page looking right. Just remember that you'd be direct formatting a particular paragraph and then later edits on the document may push the direct formatted paragraph up or down in the document ... which then might cause other visual issues.

Comment: I don't know Word well-enough, haven't really used it in years; I use Pages these days for 'quick' layout jobs… but isn't there an auto-wrap setting so you can just drag the picture around until it looks best??

Comment: I aggree with Tstsugin, moving or adjusting the the picture, seems to be a better idea.

Comment: I agree with everyone that moving the picture is a good idea; however, that was not the question that was asked.  Perhaps the question could be rewritten, but then I'm not sure it would be a good fit for Superuser.